# How to copy/paste from clipboard to tmux based on the OS version?

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin, copy-paste, tmux

I want to copy/paste to tmux based on the OS in which the .tmux.conf is loaded.

I tried this, which does not give me any error but also does not work.

```
if "test $(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 6) == 'CYGWIN' -o $(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 10) == 'MINGW32_NT'" \
  "bind C-p run 'tmux set-buffer \'$(getclip)\'; tmux paste-buffer'"
if "test $(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 5) == 'Linux'" \
  "bind C-p run 'tmux set-buffer \'$(xsel -o -b)\'; tmux paste-buffer'"
```

Comment: `Bash` is tagged to this question, but it appears to be not relevant by the use of `test` and `expr`. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

This has so many errors it's not even wrong.  Try http://www.shellcheck.net/ for a start, but really, I don't think you can tackle this without taking multiple steps back and learning the tools.  Quick hints: Don't double-quote the command you are trying to execute, and anything with `if` should have a `; then` pretty soon after. (I'm guessing this is why the shell is silent; it thinks you are still in the command pipeline argument to `if`, and is still waiting for the first `then`.)

Your immediate problem is probably better solved with a `case` statement.

```
case $(uname -s) in
  CYGWIN* | MINGW32_NT* )
    cmd=getclip;;
  Linux*)
    cmd="xsel -o -b";;
  *)
    echo "$0: Error: Not on a supported platform. Aborting." >&2
    exit 1;;
esac
bind "C-p" "run 'tmux set-buffer \'$($cmd)\'; tmux paste-buffer'";;
```

I have no input on whether this is likely to actually work; I just tried to iron out the obvious wrinkles.